# How find the real table name of one field in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query in my PHP code:

```
SELECT usr.user_id,online.online_totime
 FROM users AS usr
 LEFT JOIN online_users AS online ON online.online_user=usr.user_id
```

I want to find tables in this query with PHP. I use `mysql_field_table` and it returns "usr" and "online" as table names: those are not the real names. How I can find real table names of fields?

This query only is an example. Please don't advise me not to use `AS synonym`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could parse the query, as one [commenter of the php.net documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-table.php#70100) suggests.

Comment: And please rewrite these ereg-calls to preg-calls (ereg was deprecated in PHP 5.3, and preg is faster in general.)